# exception in UsbManager.openDevice Flutter

Tags: flutter, usbserial

I'm trying to connect my flutter app with USB serial devices to interact with it.
for that, I'm using the usb_serial  plugin and using the official example below.
Also, I'm running my app on a Desktop monitor using TvBox H96Max.

```
`import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:usb_serial/transaction.dart';
import 'package:usb_serial/usb_serial.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  UsbPort? _port;
  String _status = "Idle";
  List<Widget> _ports = [];
  List<Widget> _serialData = [];

  StreamSubscription<String>? _subscription;
  Transaction<String>? _transaction;
  UsbDevice? _device;

  TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();

  Future<bool> _connectTo(device) async {
    _serialData.clear();

    if (_subscription != null) {
      _subscription!.cancel();
      _subscription = null;
    }

    if (_transaction != null) {
      _transaction!.dispose();
      _transaction = null;
    }

    if (_port != null) {
      _port!.close();
      _port = null;
    }

    if (device == null) {
      _device = null;
      setState(() {
        _status = "Disconnected";
      });
      return true;
    }

    _port = await device.create();
    if (await (_port!.open()) != true) {
      setState(() {
        _status = "Failed to open port";
      });
      return false;
    }
    _device = device;

    await _port!.setDTR(true);
    await _port!.setRTS(true);
    await _port!.setPortParameters(115200, UsbPort.DATABITS_8, UsbPort.STOPBITS_1, UsbPort.PARITY_NONE);

    _transaction = Transaction.stringTerminated(_port!.inputStream as Stream<Uint8List>, Uint8List.fromList([13, 10]));

    _subscription = _transaction!.stream.listen((String line) {
      setState(() {
        _serialData.add(Text(line));
        if (_serialData.length > 20) {
          _serialData.removeAt(0);
        }
      });
    });

    setState(() {
      _status = "Connected";
    });
    return true;
  }

  void _getPorts() async {
    _ports = [];
    List<UsbDevice> devices = await UsbSerial.listDevices();
    if (!devices.contains(_device)) {
      _connectTo(null);
    }
    print(devices);

    devices.forEach((device) {
      _ports.add(ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.usb),
          title: Text(device.productName!),
          subtitle: Text(device.manufacturerName!),
          trailing: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text(_device == device ? "Disconnect" : "Connect"),
            onPressed: () {
              _connectTo(_device == device ? null : device).then((res) {
                _getPorts();
              });
            },
          )));
    });

    setState(() {
      print(_ports);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    UsbSerial.usbEventStream!.listen((UsbEvent event) {
      _getPorts();
    });

    _getPorts();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _connectTo(null);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('USB Serial Plugin example app'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Text(_ports.length > 0 ? "Available Serial Ports" : "No serial devices available", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
        ..._ports,
        Text('Status: $_status\n'),
        Text('info: ${_port.toString()}\n'),
        ListTile(
          title: TextField(
            controller: _textController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Text To Send',
            ),
          ),
          trailing: ElevatedButton(
            child: Text("Send"),
            onPressed: _port == null
                ? null
                : () async {
                    if (_port == null) {
                      return;
                    }
                    String data = _textController.text + "\r\n";
                    await _port!.write(Uint8List.fromList(data.codeUnits));
                    _textController.text = "";
                  },
          ),
        ),
        Text("Result Data", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
        ..._serialData,
      ])),
    ));
  }
}`
```

It gives me this error message:

```
`exception in UsbManager.openDevice
E/UsbManager(19118): java.lang.SecurityException: User has not given 10087/com.example.untitled4 permission to access device /dev/bus/usb/001/002
E/UsbManager(19118):   at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2426)
E/UsbManager(19118):   at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2410)
E/UsbManager(19118):   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2393)
E/UsbManager(19118):   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2335)
E/UsbManager(19118):   at android.hardware.usb.IUsbManager$Stub$Proxy.openDevice(IUsbManager.java:1022)
E/UsbManager(19118):   at android.hardware.usb.UsbManager.openDevice(UsbManager.java:719)
E/UsbManager(19118):   at dev.bessems.usbserial.UsbSerialPlugin.openDevice(UsbSerialPlugin.java:145)
E/UsbManager(19118):   at dev.bessems.usbserial.UsbSerialPlugin.createTyped(UsbSerialPlugin.java:186)
E/UsbManager(19118):   at dev.bessems.usbserial.UsbSerialPlugin.onMethodCall(UsbSerialPlugin.java:288)
E/UsbManager(19118):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:258)
E/UsbManager(19118):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/UsbManager(19118):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
E/UsbManager(19118):   at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/UsbManager(19118):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/UsbManager(19118):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/UsbManager(19118):   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/UsbManager(19118):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/UsbManager(19118):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7870)
E/UsbManager(19118):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/UsbManager(19118):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/UsbManager(19118):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(19118): Compat change id reported: 160794467; UID 10087; state: ENABLED
E/flutter (19118): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(UsbSerialPortAdapter, Failed to acquire USB device., null, null)
E/flutter (19118): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653:7)
E/flutter (19118): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:315:18)
E/flutter (19118): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19118): #2      UsbSerial.createFromDeviceId (package:usb_serial/usb_serial.dart:433:33)
E/flutter (19118): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19118): #3      UsbDevice.create (package:usb_serial/usb_serial.dart:333:13)
E/flutter (19118): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19118): #4      _MyAppState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:untitled4/main.dart:175:26)
E/flutter (19118): <asynchronous suspension>`
```

I was trying to show the USB serial devices and interact with it (sending data and so on).

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  I am having the same issue

Comment: You have to place the last character of your string, which serves as the string terminator, in the second parameter of Transaction.stringTerminated. This is what worked for me and sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I have to place the last character of my string, which serves as the string terminator, in the second parameter of Transaction.stringTerminated

in my case it was `Enter` button. so I put:

```
Uint8List.fromList([13, 10])
```

This is what worked for me.